# Git Push Heroku Master rejected, even though everything up to date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, heroku

I'm really confused -- I have made some changes to my app, and need to push the changes to heroku.

I have run `git add .` `git commit -m "message"`, and `git push origin master` (all my work is on master branch), and get the message saying `Everything up to date.`

HOWEVER, when I run `git push heroku master` immediately after, I get a message saying `Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.`

When I run `git pull origin master`, it says `Already up-to-date`. So I'm really baffled as to what is behind here, or what I need to do!

Comment: Have you tried `git pull heroku master` as it suggested?

Comment: Yes, I have-- edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: `git pull heroku master` not `git pull origin master`

Comment: Oh! OK--let me try...this looks promising..

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the error message..it turns out when I run git pull heroku master, it pulls down two very large images (that I don't need anymore) that have exceeded git's file size limit and kept me from pushing. So then, when I force delete those files (need to be deleted from my history), heroku thinks my branch isn't up to date, because those 2 files are missing!

Answer (score 0):

use source-tree and check the file status and then try to push.

> https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/